# Plotting two undirected graphs using the same coordinate system in MATLAB for intuitive comparison

Tags: matlab

Using the graph function in [Adjacency Matrix Graph Construction](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.html#buyz572-1), I am trying to plot a single undirected graph for two correlation matrices with edges identified by 1 and otherwise 0.

Both matrices share the same nodes but different edges. I am struggling to plot them in the same graph so that they share the same coordinate system and a clear comparison can be made straight from the graph. The two matrix graphs can be seen below:

[image]

Ideally, I would like them to be plotted on the same graph with the same node coordinate system with two different colours, one for each matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, the code below should do what you asked:

```
g1 = graph(ones(3, 3));
g2 = graph([0 1 1; 1 0 1; 1 1 0]);

f1 = figure;
hold on;
h1 = plot(g1, 'Layout', 'layered');
h2 = plot(g2, 'Layout', 'layered');

h2.XData = h1.XData;
h2.YData = h1.YData;

h2.NodeLabel={};
```

Comment: Yes, that does exactly what I wanted. Also, is there any way to rearrange the node positioning other than the default?

Comment: @GUUU Yes, `h1.XData`, `h2.XData`, `h1.YData` and `h2.YData` contain the coordinates of the graph nodes. You can set them to any values you want.